# Can I build a VS Code extension that uses sqlite that works on all platforms?

Tags: sqlite, vscode-extensions

I am writing a visual studio code extension. I want to access a sqlite database in the extension. I installed @vscode/sqlite3 and the extension works fine while debugging on my mac. However, when I build a .vsix on the mac and then attempt to install it on a windows machine, then the extension doesn't work (I get a command not found error for all the commands).

Can I create an extension using the @vscode/sqlite3 package that works on all platforms?

Answer (score 0):

There's a VS Code extension development discussion on this: [Easiest way to use sqlite in vscode extension #16](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/16). One of the VS Code maintainers, [Harald Kirschner](https://github.com/digitarald) answered suggesting to use https://sql.js.org/.

I'm not sure if `@vscode/sqlite3` is intended to be used by extension developers. [VS Code itself uses it](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1.81.0/package.json#L76), but then again, it [builds and distributes platform-specific binaries of itself](https://code.visualstudio.com/download). Based on the issue you came across, I assume the problem is that you need to have builds / get pre-built binaries for each platform and create corresponding VSIXs.

You might be interested in taking a look at how this extension does it: https://github.com/AlexCovizzi/vscode-sqlite <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>. From my understanding, it just uses the system SQLite, and requires the user to install it on platforms where it doesn't come out-of-box ([source](https://github.com/AlexCovizzi/vscode-sqlite/tree/master#requirements)) and allows the user to specify a custom installation path via settings ([source](https://github.com/AlexCovizzi/vscode-sqlite/tree/master#settings)). You could try that approach instead of bundling one. I'm pretty sure any approach that involves bundling binaries / native code will require distributing multiple binaries for each supported platform. Ex. [`ms-vscode.cpptools`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools).